# Kotlin gradle : how to tell a build.gradle.kts produce js code instead of jvm?

Tags: javascript, gradle, kotlin, jvm

The build.gradle.kts script below works fine to produces jvm code :

```
buildscript {
    extra["assertjVersion"] = "3.10.0"
    extra["gradleVersion"]  = "0.20.0"
    extra["jacocoVersion"]  = "0.8.1"
    extra["junitVersion"]   = "4.12"
    extra["kotlinVersion"]  = "1.3.61"
    extra["mockitoVersion"] = "2.12.0"
    extra["moshiVersion"]   = "1.4.0"
    extra["okhttpVersion"]  = "4.4.0"
    extra["okioVersion"]  = "2.4.3"

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath(kotlin("gradle-plugin", version = "${extra["kotlinVersion"]}"))
    classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${extra["kotlinVersion"]}")
        classpath("com.github.ben-manes:gradle-versions-plugin:${extra["gradleVersion"]}")
    }
}

plugins {
    jacoco
    java
    kotlin("jvm") version "${extra["kotlinVersion"]}"
    application
    "com.github.ben-manes.versions"
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

jacoco {
 toolVersion = "${extra["jacocoVersion"]}"
}

group = "minichain"

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:${extra["kotlinVersion"]}")
    implementation("com.squareup.moshi:moshi:${extra["moshiVersion"]}")
    implementation("com.squareup.okio:okio:${extra["okioVersion"]}")
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:${extra["okhttpVersion"]}")

    testImplementation("junit:junit:${extra["junitVersion"]}")
    testImplementation("org.mockito:mockito-core:${extra["mockitoVersion"]}")
    testImplementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:${extra["okhttpVersion"]}")
    testImplementation("org.assertj:assertj-core:${extra["assertjVersion"]}")
}

application {
    mainClassName = "io.ipfs.kotlin.MainIpfsKt"
}
```

What I need to modify to make it produce js code instead ? All my attempts to do this conversion went in error. In the best case I got *Unresolved reference: java* for all imported java modules.

Comment: May help: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/js-project-setup.html

Comment: If you try to compile Kotlin files that import classes from the JDK, then you won't be able to target js output.

Comment: @ysakhno so what can I do ? Translate all  the Java files to Kotlin ?

Comment: If you need to compile for JVM and JS with the same code base (I wonder why would you need to do that though), you'll have to use _only_ classes from the libraries that were written specifically with that in mind, like for example [Kotlin's Stdlib](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/).

Comment: @ysakhno I do not need to compile to JVM. I only got code that implements IPFS fonctionnalities and compiles to JVM. I would like to make this code produce js code. As it uses okhttp3 and other java libraries I got unresolved reference.